# .NET FileNotFoundException on correct path?

Tags: c#, .net, file, pdf, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to serve a PDF in my application like this

```
    string[] paths = {Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Content", "HelpDoc.pdf"};
    string filePath = Path.Combine(paths);
    try
    {
        return File(filePath, "application/pdf");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {...}
```

However, when hitting this in the browser, I get a "FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: C:\Users...".

- If I copy the path from the exception message into my File Explorer, it pulls up the correct file with no issue
- In my project, I've ensured the PDF's property "CopyToOutputDirectory" is "Copy always"
- I've verified several times over that the path matches the location in both my File Explorer and Rider's copy path option

I feel like I'm losing my mind over this, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Web (aspnet) / Desktop / WPF / Xamarin ? etc

Comment: Sorry for not including that, it's a web app

Comment: Then in that case you should be using HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") to get your server root directory! and map it from there!

Comment: Or may be use this: HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath

Comment: Also, not sure whether you are just trying to manipulate the file or trying to return something like FileResult from your Controller action! But this may help you for rest of the details => https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fileresult-in-asp-net-core-mvc2/

Comment: Make sure the running instance of the application has rights to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

For others having the same issue, I moved my pdf to a new directory called "pdf" inside the wwwroot directory. I then was able to access it like this:

```
string[] paths = {"wwwroot", "pdf", "HelpDoc.pdf"};
string filePath = Path.Combine(paths);
byte[] pdfBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/pdf");
```